# How the ++ operator of the const_iterator works for vector<string> in C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, std

String size is not fixed. How they made iterator knows where to point to after the increment?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<string> myVector{"ABC", "DEF"};

  for (auto p = myVector.begin(); p != myVector.end(); ++p)
    cout << *p << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `sizeof(std::string)` *is* fixed. The actual string data (which is not of fixed size) is stored elsewhere in memory, and the `std::string` object only contains a pointer to it.

So an iterator over `std::vector<std::string>` can simply advance by `sizeof(std::string)` bytes at a time.

Comment: And it should be mentioned, that an iterator can do more that a simple addition. a std::list have also an iterator, but their elements are not consecutive in memory.

Comment: do you mean the type is  `const char*`?

Comment: No, `std::string` is more than just a `char *`. It also contains a length and a capacity.

Comment: No, not at all. A `std:: string` contains at minimum a pointer to the C string memory, the size of the stored string and the capacity of the buffer. In practice things are much more complicated due to the small string optimization. It will contain local memory for small string buffer and a boolean telling if it uses the internal small.buffer or the external buffer. Moreover this boolean is "squashed" togheter with the pointer or size. So as you can see definitely not just a `const char*`.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter at all what it contains. That's just implementation detail. What matters is the size is `sizeof(T)` is always constant, that's how the language works

Comment: do we have specialization of vector STL for string? seems this is not the case for built-in types like `int`, `char`.

Comment: No, why would we need any of those?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks a lot.

Comment: All types in C++ have constant `sizeof`, attempt to alter this usually lead to undefined behavior (it is doable, but it is hard).